# Value depending on selection

Tags: arrays, shopify

Here's my code :

value="{{ product.variants[0].id }}"

I only have the first variant [0] of my products, how can i make sure i get the variant depending on selection ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried on your own?

Comment: Please copy the google.drive link to see my code;

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CXdaVjriinocElM0NlVG1oGj9qcrMTsK